# GoogleSignInAccount return null when use app Bundle in Google play

Tags: android, authentication, googlesigninaccount

I want to use Google login in my application
When I get the APK output, there is no problem and the program works easily
But when I load the program with the bundle output on the Google console, after installing and logging in and selecting the Google account, it returns a null output.
I did not use Proguard either

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(Setting.GetGoogleClientId())
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
```

After choosing the email, this value becomes null :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
  
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    

    if (requestCode == CALL_GOOGLE)
    {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
       
        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
        // account or account.getEmail() is null
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get sha1 code from Google Play Console and fix!